# Printing Batch file results to a text file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, redirect

I've created a simple batch file to reorganize a set of files/folders. It's working as it should, but I need to print the results to a log file. I need to output the results of each action (creating a directory, moving a file, rename/deleting a file). When I use *command* >> *results.txt* all I can get out of it is "1 file(s) moved." a ton of times. Here's the code:

```
FOR %%a IN (C:\scans\*.txt) DO CALL :read %%~na
TREE /f >> tree.txt
@GOTO :EOF

:read
@set FILE=%1
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN (%FILE%.txt) DO CALL :makeDir %%b %%c
@GOTO :EOF

:makeDir
@set ACCOUNT=%1
@set CHECK=%2
mkdir %ACCOUNT%
CALL :move
@GOTO :EOF

:move
MOVE %FILE%.gif %ACCOUNT%
REN %ACCOUNT%\%FILE%.gif %CHECK%.gif
DEL %FILE%.txt
@GOTO :EOF
```

How can I print to the log file (results.txt) whenever an action is performed?

EDIT: new code w/ echoes:

```
@echo off
FOR %%a IN (C:\scans\*.txt) DO CALL :read %%~na
TREE /f >> tree.txt
@GOTO :EOF

:read
@set FILE=%1
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN (%FILE%.txt) DO CALL :makeDir %%b %%c
@GOTO :EOF

:makeDir
@set ACCOUNT=%1
@set CHECK=%2
mkdir %ACCOUNT%
@echo Made directory for %ACCOUNT% >> results.txt
CALL :move
@GOTO :EOF

:move
MOVE %FILE%.gif %ACCOUNT%
@echo %FILE% moved to %ACCOUNT%
REN %ACCOUNT%\%FILE%.gif %CHECK%.gif
@echo %ACCOUNT%\%FILE% renamed %CHECK% >> results.txt
DEL %FILE%.txt
@echo %FILE% deleted. >> results.txt
@GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: You try turning ECHO on?

Comment: it's actually on, isnt it? it should echo the move and ren command invokations.

Answer (score 21):

You can add this piece of code to the top of your batch file:

```
@Echo off
SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0

:Logit
:: The rest of your code
:: ....
```

It basically redirects the output of the `:Logit` method to the `LOGFILE`. The `exit` command is to ensure the batch exits after executing `:Logit`.

Comment: When I try this, the script never gets past the `exit /b 0` line

Answer (score 16):

There's nothing wrong with your redirection of standard out to a file. Move and mkdir commands do not output anything. If you really need to have a log trail of those commands, then you'll need to explicitly echo to standard out indicating what you just executed.

The batch file, example:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd bob
ECHO I just did this: cd bob
```

Run from command line:

```
myfile.bat >> out.txt
```

or

```
myfile.bat > out.txt
```

Comment: Ok so I just tried adding lines line this:

echo >> results.txt %FILE%.gif moved to %ACCOUNT%

Doing them like that made the batch file create a directory named for every .gif and .txt in the folder... :/

Comment: You have to turn ECHO OFF, and then echo your comment text, not the actual command. See my update above.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I tried that and instead of appending the echo to the results.txt file, it created a directory called "Directory". (The text I attempted to echo was "Directory created.")

Comment: I don't know what "appending the echo to the results.txt file" means. Why not add to your post with the new version of your bat file with the ECHOs

Comment: Every time a move, rename, delete, or a mkdir occurs, I need to append that action to the results.txt file. As I was doing mkdir, for example....ECHO Directory %ACCOUNT% created. >> results.txt

That was leading to the batch file making a directory for every single text file I was iterating over.

You also said 'run [the redirect/output to file] from command line', but what I'm trying to do is output to the file each time *within* the batch file it performs that action. So I should only be running the single batch file once and everything happens in the file.

Comment: Please reread my response. Don't do standard out redirection within the script. do it from your cmd terminal: myfile.bat > out.txt.

Answer (score 6):

For Print Result to text file

we can follow

```
echo "test data" > test.txt
```

This will create test.txt file and written "test data"

If you want to append then

```
echo "test data" >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between `>` and `>>`

Answer (score 3):

For showing result of batch file in text file, you can use

this command

```
chdir > test.txt
```

This command will redirect result to test.txt.

When you open test.txt you will found current path of directory in test.txt

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Simply put all the required code in a "MAIN.BAT" file.

Step 2: Create another bat file, say MainCaller.bat, and just copy/paste these 3 lines of code:

```
REM THE MAIN FILE WILL BE CALLED FROM HERE..........
CD "File_Path_Where_Main.bat_is_located"
MAIN.BAT > log.txt
```

Step 3: Just double click "MainCaller.bat".

All the output will be logged into the text file named "log".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving DEL %FILE%.txt% to after @echo %FILE% deleted. >> results.txt so that it looks like this?

```
@echo %FILE% deleted. >> results.txt
DEL %FILE%.txt
```